# updating title of popup in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an angular reactive form (form group) and two popups angular material one for Create a new book and another to update a book.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
// import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Book } from '../models/book';
import { Categorie } from '../models/categorie';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {
  
  private subjectName = new Subject<any>(); //need to create a subject

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendUpdate(message: string) { //the component that wants to update something, calls this fn
    this.subjectName.next({ text: message }); //next() will feed the value in Subject
}

  getUpdate(): Observable<any> { //the receiver component calls this function 
      return this.subjectName.asObservable(); //it returns as an observable to which the receiver funtion will subscribe
  }

  /**
     * Get all book's categories as reference data from Backend server.
     */
    loadBooks(): Observable<Book[]>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
      return this.http.get<Book[]>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/allbooks', {headers: headers});
  }
    
    /**
     * Get all book's categories as reference data from Backend server.
     */
     loadCategories(): Observable<Categorie[]>{
         let headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
         headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
         return this.http.get<Categorie[]>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/category/api/allCategories', {headers: headers});
     }
     
    /**
     * Save a new Book object in the Backend server data base.
     * @param book
     */
     saveBook(book: Book): Observable<Book>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post<Book>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/addBook2', book, {headers: headers});
     }
     
     /**
      * Update an existing Book object in the Backend server data base.
      * @param book
      */
      updateBook2(book: Book): Observable<Book>{
          return this.http.put<Book>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/updateBook', book);
      }

      updateBook(book: Book): Observable<Book>{
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post<Book>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/updateBook2', book, {headers: headers});
       }
      
      /**
       * Delete an existing Book object in the Backend server data base.
       * @param book
       */
       deleteBook(book: Book): Observable<string>{
           return this.http.delete<string>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/deleteBook/'+book.id);
       }
     
     /**
      * Search books by isbn
      * @param isbn
      */
     searchBookByIsbn(isbn: string): Observable<Book>{
         return  this.http.get<Book>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/searchByIsbn?isbn='+isbn);
     }
     
    /**
     * Search books by title
     * @param title
     */
     searchBookByTitle(title: string): Observable<Book[]>{
             return this.http.get<Book[]>(environment.apiUrl+'/rest/book/api/searchByTitle?title='+title);
     }

     form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      $key: new FormControl(null),
      titre: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      auteur: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      isbNum: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      totExemplaire: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      publiDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      categ: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      
    });

    insertbook(book) {
      
    }

    initializeFormGroup() {
      this.form.setValue({
        $key: null,
        titre: '',
        auteur: '',
        isbNum: '',
        totExemplaire: '',
        publiDate: '',
        categ:0
      });
    }

    deleteAbook(bookId: number):Observable<any> {
      let url = "http://localhost:8181/book/remove";
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')
        })
      };
      return this.http.post(url,bookId,httpOptions);
    }
  
    populateForm(book) {
      this.form.setValue({
        $key: null,
        titre: book['title'],
        auteur: book['author'],
        isbNum: book['isbn'],
        totExemplaire: book['totalExamplaries'],
        publiDate: book['releaseDate'],
        categ:book['category'].code
      });
    }

}

<div class="container">
    <div fxFlex="60">
        <div class="search-div mr-2">
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCreate()">
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Create
            </button>
            <mat-form-field class="ml-2 search-form-field" floatLabel="never">
              <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
              <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"*ngIf="searchKey"  (click)="onSearchClear()">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="listData">

                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="titre">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Titre </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="auteur">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Auteur </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.author}} </td>
                </ng-container>

               
                <ng-container matColumnDef="isbn">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Isbn </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.isbn}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="date enregistrement">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date enregistrement </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.registerDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                
                <ng-container matColumnDef="date publication">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date publication </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.releaseDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                      <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
                      <button mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog(row)" color="warn"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
                    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                      Loading data...
                    </mat-footer-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
                    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                      No data.
                    </mat-footer-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>

            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Book } from '../models/book';
import { BookService } from '../services/book.service';
import { BookComponent } from '../book/book.component';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
//import { BookComponent } from '../book/book.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booklist',
  templateUrl: './booklist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booklist.component.css']
})
export class BooklistComponent implements OnDestroy {

  public pbookList;

  booksResult: Book[] ;

  dataSource;

  searchKey: string;

  dialogTitle: string;

  private subscriptionName: Subscription; //important to create a subscription

  messageReceived: any;
    

 // private dialog: MatDialog;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['titre', 'auteur','isbn', 'date enregistrement', 'date publication', 'actions'];
  // dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Book>(this.booksResult);
  listData: MatTableDataSource<Book>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
    // subscribe to sender component messages
    this.subscriptionName= this.bookService.getUpdate().subscribe
    (message => { //message contains the data sent from service
    this.messageReceived = message; //kind of a flag here
    this.chargerLivres(); //or ngOnInit() whichever responsible for laoding
    });
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chargerLivres();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Book>(this.booksResult);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { // It's a good practice to unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
            this.subscriptionName.unsubscribe();
        }

  applyFilter() {
    this.listData.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  chargerLivres(){
    console.log("list des books avant affcihage");
      this.bookService.loadBooks().subscribe(
              (result: Book[]) => {
                console.log("list des books : ",result);
                this.booksResult = result;
                this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(result);
                this.pbookList=result;
                console.log("bookResult : ",this.booksResult);
              },
              error => {
                console.log("Erreur : ",error);
              }
      );
  }

  onCreate() {
    this.bookService.initializeFormGroup();
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    //dialogConfig.width = "350px";
    this.dialog.open(BookComponent,dialogConfig);
  }

  onEdit(row){
    let myValue = 1;
    this.bookService.form.get("$key").setValue(myValue);
    console.log("row : ",row);
    console.log("titre : ",row['title']);
    let cat = row['category'];
    let code = cat.code;
    let label = cat.label;
    console.log("category : ",row['category']);
    console.log("code : ",code);
    console.log("label : ",label);
    console.log("label2 : ",row['category'].label);
    this.bookService.populateForm(row);
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "60%";
    this.dialog.open(BookComponent,dialogConfig);
  }


  openDialog(row) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Voulez-vous supprimer ce livre?',
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Supprimer!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Annuler'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        console.log("row pour deleted: ",row);
         this.bookService.deleteBook(row).subscribe(data => {
          this.bookService.sendUpdate('A msg/flag');
          Swal.fire(
            'Effectué!',
            'Le livre a été supprimé.',
            'success'
          )
          console.log("data return with remove : ",data);
      },error => {
        console.log("Erreur lors de la suppression du livre: ",error);
      });
    } 
    })
  }

}

<mat-toolbar>
    <span>{{service.form.controls['$key'].value?"Modifier un livre":"Nouveau livre"}}</span>
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <button class="btn-dialog-close ml-auto" mat-stroked-button (click)="onClose()" tabIndex="-1"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <form [formGroup]="service.form" class="normal-form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="300px">
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <div class="controles-container">
          <input type="hidden" formControlName="$key">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="titre" matInput placeholder="Titre*" >
            <mat-error>Le titre est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="auteur" matInput placeholder="Auteur*" >
            <mat-error>Le nom de l'auteur est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="isbNum" matInput placeholder="Isbn*" >
            <mat-error>L'isbn est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <div class="controles-container">
          <input type="hidden" value="test" name="test">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="totExemplaire" type="number" matInput placeholder="Total Exemplaires*" >
            <mat-error>Le nombre d'exemplaire est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="publiDate" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" matInput placeholder="Date publication*" >
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "myDatepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
            </mat-datepicker-toggle><mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
            <mat-error>Le date est obligatoire.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="categ" placeholder="Categorie" >
              <ng-container >
                <mat-option value="C">Cuisine</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="I">Informatique</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="J">Jeunesse</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="M">Mathématiques</mat-option>
              </ng-container>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <div class="button-row">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mr-2" type="submit" [disabled]="service.form.invalid">Envoyer</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClear()">Effacer</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </form>

import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { Book } from '../models/book';
import { BookService } from '../services/book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {

  public book = new Book();

  constructor(public service: BookService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<BookComponent>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.service.form.valid) {
      const formValue = this.service.form.value;
      this.book.author = formValue['auteur'];
      this.book.isbn = formValue['isbNum'];
      //this.book.releaseDate = formValue['publiDate'];
      this.book.category.code = formValue['categ'];
      this.book.title = formValue['titre'];
      this.book.totalExamplaries = formValue['totExemplaire'];
      var localDate = new Date(formValue['publiDate']);
      if(localDate.getTimezoneOffset() < 0){
          localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() - localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
      }else{
        localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() + localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
      }
      console.log("get value form insert : ",this.service.form.value);
      this.book.releaseDate = localDate;
      if (!this.service.form.get('$key').value){
        console.log("get $key value form insert : ",this.service.form.get('$key').value);
        console.log("book to insert 24 : ",this.book);
        console.log("formValue['categ'] ",formValue['categ']);
        this.saveNewBook(this.book);
      }
      else {
        console.log("get $key value form update : ",this.service.form.get('$key').value);
        this.updateABook(this.book);
        this.service.form.reset();
        this.service.initializeFormGroup();
        console.log("Categorie : ",formValue['categ']);
      }
      this.onClose();
    }
  }

  /**
* Save new book
* @param book
*/
saveNewBook(book: Book){
  this.spinner.show();
  this.service.saveBook(book).subscribe(
          (result: Book) => {
              console.log("Resultat du livre : ",result);
             if(result.id){
              this.service.sendUpdate('A msg/flag');
                this.spinner.hide();
                 console.log("Le livre a ajoute avec id : ",result.id);
                // this.buildMessageModal('Save operation correctly done');
             }
          },
          error => {
               this.spinner.hide();
               console.log("erreur survenue lors de  ajout : ",error);
              // this.buildMessageModal('An error occurs when saving the book data');
          }
  );
}


  /**
* Update a book
* @param book
*/
updateABook(book: Book){
  this.service.updateBook(this.book).subscribe(
    (result: Book) => {
      console.log("Resultat maj livre : ",result);
     if(result.id){
      this.service.sendUpdate('A msg/flag');
        console.log("Le livre est maj id : ",result.id);
     }
  },
    error => {
      console.log("update book est en erreur : ",error);
    }
  );
}

openDialog(book:Book) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Voulez-vous supprimer ce livre?',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Supprimer!',
    cancelButtonText: 'Annuler'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
       this.service.deleteBook(book).subscribe(data => {
        this.service.sendUpdate('A msg/flag');
        Swal.fire(
          'Effectué!',
          'Le livre a été supprimé.',
          'success'
        )
        console.log("data return with remove : ",data);
    },error => {
      console.log("Erreur lors de la suppression du livre: ",error);
    });
  } 
  })
}

  onClear() {
    this.service.form.reset();
    this.service.initializeFormGroup();
  }

  onClose() {
    this.service.form.reset();
    this.service.initializeFormGroup();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  

  /**
* Save zone local date to the book releaseDate property : 
*   there is a recognized problem with datepicker @angular/material timezone conversion.
* @param book
*/
setLocalDateToDatePicker(book: Book){
  var localDate = new Date(book.releaseDate);
  if(localDate.getTimezoneOffset() < 0){
      localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() - localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
  }else{
    localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() + localDate.getTimezoneOffset() );
  }
  book.releaseDate = localDate;
}

}
```

In my source code, you have an angular service, a service common to both bookcomponent and bookcomponentlist.
My problem is exactly on the second line of my bookcomponent htlm :

```
<span>{{service.form.controls['$key'].value?"Modifier un livre":"Nouveau livre"}}</span>
```

My goal is to be able to dynamically change the value of my popup when I'm creating or updating. Unfortunately, I can't .
Anyone have an idea ?

here is the stackblitz link in my source code : https://stackblitz.com/github/lnquaidorsay/bibliofront  and click to books for see the result .

Comment: I think the problem is BookService is reinitialize the form variable when opening the dialog box for BookComponent.

Comment: Hi @Harshana, how can i resolve it ? Have you an idea ?

Comment: first question is it updating the book changes correctly? if yes the issue is something else. if not simply pass the data in Ex: dialogConfig:{data:book} or make the form in BookService as a BehaviourSubject and subscribe on it's value in BookComponent.